# Java - replacing word.charAt(i) with word.charAt(i+1) and making word.charAt(i+1) = 'A'

Tags: java, replace, charat

I need to look at each word in an array, so I made a `for loop` with `array[i]` equaling `String word`, then I made another `for loop` that has an `if statement` that is changing `word.charAt(i)` with `word.charAt(i+1)` and changing `word.charAt(i+1) = 'A'`.

The objective is to 'encrypt' the word by checking if `i` is equal to 'A', and if it is then switching positions with `i+1`.

Here is my code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < unchangedFileInput.length; i++) {
    String word = unchangedFileInput[i];
    for(int v = 0; v < word.length();v++) {
        if (word.charAt(v) == 'A'
                && word.charAt(v+1) != 'A' 
                && word.length() > 1) {
            char[] mywordChars = word.toCharArray();
            temp = mywordChars[v+1];
            mywordChars[v] = mywordChars[v+1];
            mywordChars[v+1] = 'A';
            word = String.valueOf(mywordChars);
        } else {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

unchangedFileInput is an array that has the values of:

```
AVACADO
CHICKEN 
BACON 
AARDVARK
```

This is what the final result should look like:

```
AVACADO = VACADAO 
CHICKEN = UNCHANGED 
BACON = BCAON 
AARDVARK = ARADVRAK 
NAAN = NANA
```

Comment: You haven't stated what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that you don't go past the array limit first. I created a test framework,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] unchangedFileInput = { "AVACADO", "CHICKEN", "BACON",
            "AARDVARK", "NAAN" };
    String[] changedFileInput = new String[unchangedFileInput.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < unchangedFileInput.length; i++) {
        changedFileInput[i] = transformName(unchangedFileInput[i]);
        System.out.printf("%s = %s%n", unchangedFileInput[i],
                changedFileInput[i]);
    }
}
```

And then wrapped your code in a method (and just created a new `String` with a `StringBuilder` removing the array conversions),

```
private static String transformName(String in) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0, len = in.length(); i < len; i++) {
        char ch = in.charAt(i);
        if (ch == 'A') {
            if (i + 1 < in.length() && in.charAt(i + 1) != 'A') {
                sb.append(in.charAt(i + 1));
                i++;
            }
        }
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And I get your requested output,

```
AVACADO = VACADAO
CHICKEN = CHICKEN
BACON = BCAON
AARDVARK = ARADVRAK
NAAN = NANA
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you want you need to start the iteration from the end of the word to the beginning, otherwise, when you swap 'A' with the following character, you will have the 'A' again at the next iteration. If you start from the end, you will hit each 'A' only once.

Answer (score -1):

Using this code

```
for(int v = 0; v < word.length();v++) {
                if (word.charAt(v) == 'A' && word.charAt(v+1)
```

You will get an IndexOutOfBoundsException at the end of the String.

And if you are talking about the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` error!!

I suggested, `v < word.length() - 1;`

Comment: Hey My DVer, why the DV ?

Comment: if you are talking about the IndexOutOfBoundsException error that I suggested, then try `v < word.length() - 1;`